# How can I calculate recall and precision using c++?

Tags: c++, opencv, boost, eigen

Is there any c++ library like Boost,Eigen, OpenCV which can calculate recall and precision?

Comment: What have you found so far?

Comment: I need library where I will give rank matrix/distance matrix, and it will calculate recall and precision.

Answer (score 5):

A library for precision and recall is not required. It can be coded easily.

`precision = tp / (tp + fp)` and `recall = tp / (tp + fn)`

Let,

N - number of keypoints in the first image that are also visible on the second image

N1 - number of keypoints in the first image that have been matched.

n - number of the correct matches found by the matcher

Then,

n/N1 - precision

n/N - recall

take a look at the function here: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/detector_descriptor_matcher_evaluation.cpp